# Custom menu get title of the active menu's parent item

Tags: php, cms, menu, module

I can get the title of the active menu using

```
$menu = &Jsite::getMenu();
$menuname = $menu->getActive()->title;
```

But how can I access it's parent title?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$parent = $menu->getItem( $menu->getActive()->parent_id );
$parentname = $parent->title
```

If you need the link

```
$parentlink = JRoute::_( $parent->link . '&Itemid=' . $parent->id );
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, you should check the return value of getActive() because there maybe is no active menu and you get a non-object back (I think null)

Answer (score 1):

The method getActive return a object with the active menu properties including the parent_id. The JMenu class has a method getItem($id), where $id is a menu id. This method return the same type of object that getActive. So, you can do something like this:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$parent_id = $menu->getActive()->parent_id;
$parent_title = $menu->getItem($parent_id)->title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can get the active menu, you can get the rest by getting the `tree`. This is usefull to traverse the item list, not just the parent!

So that you understand better, I'm spliting the answer in parts:

1.
Create a variable for the active menu (for simplicity and portability):

```
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
```

2.
Pick the previous/parent menu by getting the previous item in the tree:

```
$parent_item_id = $active->tree[count($active->tree) - 2];
```

**NOTE:** the `tree` is an array, and starts with zero, that's why I am subtracting by 2.

3.
Finally get the menu title:

```
$menu->getItem($parent_item_id)->title
```

Mind you that you also need to add some checks to see if there is an active menu, and/or other error checks.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$menu = &JSite::getMenu();`, because it is not a static function. The correct way is to use the code as specified by @me7hos.